# gen_server named timer_server caused timer module functions to not return

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I created a supervisor that spawned a `gen_server` I called `timer_server`.  One of the tasks of this `timer_serve`r is to manage registration and call `timer:send_interval` to send a message to a pid on a certain interval.

However, in the init of the `gen_server`, where I call `timer:send_interval` I was getting a lockup.  The documentation said the timer: functions return immediately, so this was very troubling.

When I renamed my `gen_server` to `record_timer_server` this problem cleared up.  My question is two fold then:

1. Why could I create a registered process `timer_server`, if there already was one when `timer:start()` was called by my application starting up?
2. Once started, why would this function not cause a badmatch finding the name, if it was calling in to my `timer_server` using the `send_interval` function?

I don't think code is necessary but I can update to add some if requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be recreated simply by doing the following which hangs on the call to timer:send_interval.

```
1> register(timer_server, self()).
true
2> timer:send_interval(5000, self(), hello).
```

While this fails...

```
1> timer:send_interval(5000, self(), hello).
{ok,{interval,#Ref<0.0.0.32>}}
2> register(timer_server, self()).
** exited: {badarg,[{erlang,register,[timer_server,<0.30.0>]},
```

So, it seems that the first call to timer tries to start a process called timer_server, and hangs if you've taken this name first.

As to why it hangs timer.erl does:

```
ensure_started() ->
    case whereis(timer_server) of
        undefined -> 
            C = {timer_server, {?MODULE, start_link, []}, permanent, 1000, 
                worker, [?MODULE]}
            supervisor:start_child(kernel_safe_sup, C),  % kernel_safe_sup
            ok;
        _ -> ok
    end.
```

which returns fine, followed by a gen_server:call to timer_server.  Your process then gets stuck waiting for itself to respond.